# Hide overflow from given edge of box only in CSS

Tags: html, css, 3d, styles, overflow

**Hi I want to make a 3D box design**, That should looks like ***object coming out from box***.

- Here one images will be there inside a box.
- Image will be bigger than container box.
- I want to **hide overflow from left and bottom only**.

I am struggling for making this design since 4 hours, but not getting result and solutions.

**Here is the demo that i wants to build:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check this

I use grid layout model. You can place your image inside .container has `position: absolute;` on it

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


img,
picture {
  max-width: 100%;
  display:block;
}

body{
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}


.container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr ;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 3fr 1fr;
  width: 750px;
  height: 750px;
  /* background-color: tomato; */
  position: relative;
}

.box{
  position: relative;
  background-color: tomato;
  z-index:2;
}


.box-1{
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
  grid-row: 1;
  z-index:1;
}

.box-2{
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  z-index:1;
}

.box-3{
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  z-index:1;
}


.box-4{
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1 / -1;
  
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box-5{
  grid-column: 2 / -1;
  grid-row: 3;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box-6{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="box-1 box"></div>
      <div class="box-2 box"></div>
      <div class="box-3 box"></div>
      <div class="box-4 box"></div>
      <div class="box-5 box"></div>
      <div class="box-6">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/780x400" alt="" />
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maximum time I work on flexbox. So let me try this code.

Comment: Hey bro your answer is just like @mohammad answer, Think about the content that will come after this box. that content will be hide with ugly look.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more ?

Comment: You are putting it in container, After this more html content will come in my website. So your box-5 div will hide my those content.

Comment: You are only replacing my overflow with similar color with background. That is not good idea.

Comment: Changing positions of boxes will help too if you set the background of that grid container as the same color of the outer box.  You can make size of boxes smaller, and when some content overflow nothing will happen.    @VIKESIR